# jQuery/Javascript - Showing only tr's with td's matching an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a table to show only rows which have td's that match one of the array's values.

I've created a dumbed down jsfiddle of this specific part of the code. I've got no clue why this doesn't work, so would appreciate help.

The part that doesn't work is apparently finding matching to the array values td's.

Here is the code:

```
        $('body').on('click', '#zipButton', function() {
                    var arrayTest = [123,124,125,126]
                    var tr = find('tbody > tr');
                    $(tr).hide();
                            for(i=0;i<arrayTest.length;i++) {
                            $('.zipTd').each(function () {
                                ($(this).text() == arrayTest[i].toString()) ? $(this).parent().show() : $(this).parent().hide();
                            });   
                            };
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m4orLpd3/1/

Thanks

Comment: in my opinion, what you should try is create a new array of the only matching element you want to show up. Then do the search and add the element in. After that, just show up the new array :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that would not work, since this is a dumbed down version. The original doesn't even display the numbers by which they are filtered, its a job listings table. But  thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using jquery's [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and javascript [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do that.

Check the following example:

```js
var array = [123, 124, 125, 126];

$('body').on('click', 'button', function() {

  var filter = function() {

    var match = false;

    $(this).find('td').each(function() {

      var currentText = $(this).text();

      var filtered = array.filter(function(value) {
        return value == currentText;
      });

      if (filtered.length > 0) {
        match = true;
      }

    });

    return match;

  };

  $('tr').hide().filter(filter).show();

});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button">trigger</button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>dummy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>124</td>
    <td>dummy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>127</td>
    <td>dummy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>dummy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>324</td>
    <td>dummy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>127</td>
    <td>dummy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>523</td>
    <td>dummy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>144</td>
    <td>dummy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>127</td>
    <td>dummy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly and doesn't load the client too much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter for this

```
$('body').on('click', '#zipButton', function () {
    var arrayTest = [123, 124, 125, 126]
    $(".zipTd").filter(function () {
        return arrayTest.indexOf(parseInt($(this).text().trim())) == -1 
    }).closest("tr").hide();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m4orLpd3/4/)

**Edit**

```
$('body').on('click', '#zipButton', function () {
    $(".zipTd").closest("tr").hide();
    var arrayTest = [123, 124, 125, 126]
    $(".zipTd").filter(function () {
        return arrayTest.indexOf(parseInt($(this).text().trim())) >= 0
    }).closest("tr").show();
});
```

[**Edited Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m4orLpd3/11/)

Comment: Thanks, but that does the opposite of what is needed. It hides the values that I need to display and displays the values that I need to hide..

Comment: Thanks, it kind of works now. The only issue is that now it hangs the browser for 10 seconds, while your previous code took about a second or two, is there a specific reason why it takes forever now? For your info, the amount of rows in my table is approximately 2500

Comment: Thanks for the help, the other person's code works faster even with your new edits. I highly appreciate your help! would upvote if I had more rep :(